# Packaging an AWS MarketPlace application for Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-marketplace

Is is possible to package an AWS marketplace application as an Elastic Beanstalk artefact?

For a java application for instance is there a way to register the .war file as a marketplace application, to be launched in beanstalk, instead of an AMI to be instantiated in EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating AMI, you can create cloud formation template of Elastic Beanstalk with your application and sell it to AWS Marketplace.